# Discord bot that gives role to the user I react on part2

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been working on my discord bot to make it give verified roles to members that I checkmark react to them, I've been running into issue lately and I hope someone can fix it

I'm trying to make the bot give "Temporary" role when I use ❎ but I keep getting this message

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'role' referenced before assignment
```

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 1030905311231483904:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.id == '1032324082110304288':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Temporary')
            role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Not-Verified')

        if role is not None:
            msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            member = msg.author
            channel = await member.create_dm()
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await member.remove_roles(role2)
                await channel.send("You have been Verified! Enjoy 2883 discord server! Please select your alliance role and troop type!")
                print('done')
            else:
                print('member not found')
        else:
            print('role not found')
    else:
        pass
```

This is the code I'm currently trying to work on

And this is the code that works perfectly for me, Idk why changing the Emoji line from `emoji.name` to `emoji.id` makes me get this error above

Answer (score 2):

`role` is only declared inside of an if-statement, so if that if-statement is not entered then the variable `role` doesn't exist. Your error suggests that this is the case, as it is "referenced before assignment".

```py
       if payload.emoji.id == '1032324082110304288':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Temporary')
            role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Not-Verified')

        if role is not None:  # <- "role" doesn't exist if the if above ^ is False
```

This is indeed the case. Your predicate reads `payload.emoji.id == '1032324082110304288'`, which is impossible. ID's are **ints** in discord.py, **never strings**, so this if-statement will **never be True**. This means that **`role` never exists**.

```py
'1032324082110304288' # <- this is a string
1032324082110304288 # <- this is an int
```

In other cases, where a *different* emoji was used, you'll still just be using that variable even though it won't exist either. When conditionally creating variables, you should always make sure that either

- They always exist: create those variables in every single branch (including the `else`-branch) or define them above the condition

```py
some_var = None
if condition:
    some_var = "some_value"

# At this point, some_var always exists

if condition:
    some_var = "some_value"
else:
    some_var = "None"

# At this point, some_var always exists as well
```

or

- They're never used in case they *don't exist*: either put all logic that uses them inside of the if-statement, or simply `return` out of the function in the `else` case.

```py
if condition:
    some_var = "some_value"
    # You can use some_var here, it's declared on the line above
else:
    # Don't use some_var here, it doesn't exist
```

Docs showing the type of `Emoji.id`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji.id